# Valgrind illegal instruction AVX

Tags: c++, c, valgrind

I receive some error when evaluating my program using valgrind. More precisely, I get errors like

vex amd64->IR: unhandled instruction bytes: 0xC5 0xF8 0x28 0x0 0xC5 0xF8 0x29 0x45
...
...
Illegal instruction

I isolated the problem to a very simple example

```
#include <immintrin.h>
int main() {
  float f __attribute__((aligned(16))); // No need to be aligned
  f = 2.0f;
  __m128 a = _mm_broadcast_ss(&f);
  return 0;
}
```

The program is compiled using gcc with the options -mavx. If the SSE2 instruction _mm_set1_ps is used instead, the same error occurs but only when compiled with -mavx. When compiling the program using -msse2, valgrind reports no errors.

I suspect this is a valgrind bug, but can't find any reports on this for x86. My machine is a Core-i7 Sandy-Bridge and valgrind version 3.7.0.

If anyone have a better alternative to valgrind for register-aware programming, I would like to know.

Thanks in advance

Comment: As an aside to the Valgrind version not being up to date, while SSE requires 16-byte alignment, you'll want 32-byte alignment for AVX instructions.

Comment: You are right, but the instruction behind the _mm_broadcast_ss requires no alignment of the right argument

Comment: I was just making the note in case other things in the rest of your code were aligned similarly.

Comment: The `AVX` instruction-set also includes new encodings for old instructions (`VEX/EVEX`-prefixes), which can improve performance for mixing legacy `SSE` with new `AVX`-instructions by avoiding partial register writes. Unfortunately this means that your processor (or emulator, as the case may be) must support these if you want to use `-mavx`, even when you use `SSE` instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mm_broadcast_ss` translates to a single CPU instruction and it requires the [AVX instruction set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Vector_Extensions).  You may need a more up-to-date valgrind to support that instruction, at [least release 3.8.0 (10 August 2012)](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/dist.news.html).

See the [Valgrind core documentation](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core.html) for an explanation.

Comment: Thanks for the link. It is a little funny though that replacing the instruction with an SSE2 instruction also fails if the program is compiled with -mavx. The assembly may reveal that the _mm_set1_ps is translated to an AVX broadcast instruction. I will update the valgrind

Comment: @JensMunk:  Maybe `-mavx` is ignored?  That might happen for a 32-bit compile.  Or there could be other options which force use of a built-in function instead.  See [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.3/gcc/X86-Built_002din-Functions.html#X86-Built_002din-Functions).

Comment: Just checked the assembly output, _mm_set1_ps is converted to a vbroadcastss instruction, when using the option -mavx. It explains the errors I see.

Answer (score 5):

You are using very old valgrind 3.7.0 which was released in Nov 2011. It does not support AVX / AVX2.

Support for AVX was added in 3.8.0 and for AVX2 in 3.9.0. The latest available version is 3.10.1 released in Nov 2014.

[Current releases](http://valgrind.org/downloads/current.html)

[Release notes](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/dist.news.html)